# How to Detect Collision or Trigger event in unity When both object is kinematic?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, unityscript, eventtrigger

I have two object in my game both object have 2d physics material.

Both object static means there is no physics apply on that.

Now when I move one object pragmatically, then it should called CollisionEnter event or trigger enter event, but non of them is getting called. every thing is work fine If I remove is kinematic property from one object.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) for a complete overview on possible collision combinations.

For what concern your case:

**Trigger**

If you want to receive trigger messages between 2 objects, that's possible but at least one of them must have a `RigidBody` (kinematic or non kinematic).

**Collision**

If you want to receive collision messages between to objects, at least one of them must have a **non kinematic** `RigidBody`.